# What is the difference between the plugin and feature tags in config.xml?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

What is the difference between the [`<feature>`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/#feature) and [`<plugin>`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/#plugin) tags in Cordova's [`config.xml`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html) file?

It seems that a `<plugin>` tag adds a plugin and can also pass variables, whereas the `<feature>` tag only adds variables for existing plugins or features included in Cordova's core. Is this correct?

```
// Plugin tag
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.1" />

// Plugin tag including feature
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" spec="6.0.3">
    <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Scan some stuff" />
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example doesn't contain `<feature>` tags, here is an example that is included in most Ionic apps:

```
<feature name="StatusBar">
  <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
</feature>
```

The difference is in what you can do with these tags. The `<plugin>` tag allows you to define which plugins your app depends on including things like a version number. If the plugin author has created such functionality, you can also pass variables to the plugin using the `<variable>` tag.

With the `<feature>` tag, you can tell Cordova which package name is used for a certain plugin. That is what is happening in the example, for the StatusBar plugin we are telling Cordova to look for a package with the name `CDVStatusBar`. The other available attribute is `onload`, which tells Cordova that the plugin needs to be initialized when the app is being loaded.

This information can be found in the Cordova documentation, which you can find [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/#feature). They also mention the following in the documentation:

> **NOTE: Most of the time, you do NOT want to set this directly.**

I think it is good to know about the `<feature>` tag, but don't think that you should worry about them too much. Just include them when the plugin requires it and leave it alone otherwise.